# How can I remove yellow, blue and red colors from color ramp in Xcode's particle editor?

Tags: xcode

[image: color ramp]

How can I remove yellow, blue and red colors from color ramp in Xcode's particle editor?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Click (and hold) the color indicator and then drag it (e.g. down) off the color ramp.

Comment: This one was not intuitive at all :)